# Alert if class is used more than once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert, visible

In the following Fiddle, you can click to select rows in the table. If you click the 'Execute'  button, an alert will tell you if the class .row_selected is visible or not. This is all working, now I need to elaborate on the rows selected part. The user can only 'Execute' one row at a time, so if one row is selected - yay. If more than one are selected, an error message asking to select only one row. One row to rule them all. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/BWCBX/34/

**jQuery**

```
$("button").click(function () {
    if ($(".row_selected").is(":visible")) {
        alert('Row(s) are selected.')
    } else {
        alert('No rows are selected.')
    }
});
```

Comment: Sure... test if more than one row has the row_selected class... possibly by using .length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition with `.length` see below,

```
if ($(".row_selected").length > 1) {  //more than one row selected
    alert('Please select one row');
} else if ($(".row_selected").length) { //one row selected
    alert('Row(s) are selected.')
} else {  // none selected
    alert('No rows are selected.')
}
```

Seems like the `row_selected` is applied to the row only on selection so you don't need `:visible` check.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/7wrJC/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to get the number of the selected rows:

```
if (1 === $(".row_selected:visible").length) {
    // do something
}
```